# Контекстное меню android не подключается

Tags: java, android, android-context-menu

пытаюсь подключить контекстное меню к элементам списка, но ничего не происходит, в чем может быть проблема?

```
public class DetailsFragment extends Fragment {
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        plansList = (ListView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        registerForContextMenu(plansList);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu_details, menu);
    }
}
```

Также добавил следующий код, тоже не работает:

```
    plansList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CharSequence message = "Нажатие";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
```

Использую свой адаптер, наследующийся от ArrayAdapter:

```
public class PlanAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Plan> {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private int layout;
private List<Plan> plans;

public PlanAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Plan> plans) {
    super(context, resource, plans);
    this.plans = plans;
    this.layout = resource;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(this.layout, parent, false);

    TextView nameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView durationOfProcedureView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
    TextView timeView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
    TextView durationOfTreatmentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dureationOfTreatment);
    CheckBox include = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.include);
    TextView interval = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.frequency);


    Plan plan = plans.get(position);

    nameView.setText(plan.getName());
    timeView.setText(plan.getTimeString());
    durationOfTreatmentView.setText(String.format(view.getResources().getString(R.string.durationOfTreatment), plan.getCountMadeProcedures(), plan.getDurationOfTreatment()));
    durationOfProcedureView.setText(String.format(view.getResources().getString(R.string.durationOfProcedure), plan.getDurationOfProcedure()));
    include.setChecked(plan.isIncluded());
    interval.setText(String.format(view.getResources().getString(R.string.every_day), plan.getInterval()));

    return view;
}

}
```

Comment: Где-то я это уже видел... Точно у Вас в макете `ListView` имеет `id` `list_item`?

Comment: У меня помимо этого кода есть ещё работа с этим элементом, так что да, есть

Comment: Вы что-то странное делаете. Зачем вам во фрагменте иметь ссылку на ListView из активити? Может у вас ListView таки в разметке фрагмента, не активити? Если всё же в ней, то так делать неправильно... В таком случае вам, возможно, поможет перенос кода для контекстного меню в активити. Если всё же во фрагменте, то надо инициализировать ListView так: `plansList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list_item);`

Comment: ListView в разметке фрагмента, да, ошибся. Поменял на getView, но ничего не поменялось, также не срабатывает ничего. Добавил также код обработки нажатия, тоже не срабатывает(сверху добавил в вопрос)

Comment: Неужели никто не поможет?((

Comment: Я надеюсь это не весь код фрагмента, и в нём есть метод `onCreateView`? Покажите этот метод (а лучше весь фрагмент), разметку фрагмента и если в логах есть что интересно-красного - их тоже.

Comment: @piller97, кажется я понял, в чём у вас проблема. Вы вешаете слушатель контекстного меню на список и ожидаете, что он будет срабатывать при нажатии на его элементы? Если да, то это работает иначе - надо слушатель на отдельные элементы вешать. Слушатель нажатий из вопроса на список лучше не использовать и вместо него делать это в адаптере списка. Он у вас есть? Или вы используете готовый адаптер? Если нет - покажите адаптер. Если в нём есть слушатели нажатий, то внешний слушатель работать не будет.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, на список. Использую свой адаптер (добавил сверху код).

Comment: Меня что очень смущает - у меня при нажатии на элемент списка не подсвечивается, ну, если создать список из строк, то они будут реагировать на тыки, а здесь реакции ноль, только скроллинг и вкл/выкл чекбокса у элемента списка

Comment: О боже, у меня работает!!! Там всего то надо было в разметке элемента списка добавить блокировку фокусировки: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants".))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, в разметке элемента списка необходимо добавить блокировку фокусировки: `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`.
В общем виде:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```